# К чему сводится описание процесса отладки и тестирования?

Tags: c#, .net, тестирование, отладка

В общем есть некоторое ПО и нужно расписать как оно отлаживалось и тестировалось.

Как это , обычно, делается?

С консольным приложением, на мой взгляд, все легко, а вот как быть в WinForms?

Делать скриншоты на каждую кнопку и описывать то, что это ожидаемое поведение?

И вообще, можно ли считать что отладка=тестированию? На мой взгляд, очень близкие значения...

Comment: А оно (такое описание процесса) в природе существует?  Описание набора тестов и инструкция по их запуску -- да,  а вот сочинений на тему "как мы отлаживали ..." ни разу не писал и чужих подобных отчетов не видел.

Comment: По поводу "отладка=тестирование". В принципе эти процессы должны быть *разнонаправленными*. Цель отладки -- добиться, чтобы программа соответствовала спецификациям. А вот цель тестирования д.б. **прямо противоположенной** (как ни странно это звучит) -- найти в программе ошибки. Однако, на практике 99% программистов не в силах заниматься  деструктивной деятельностью со своим творением и вместо поиска ошибок в процессе тестирования занимаются доказательствами того, что программа работает правильно.

Answer (score 5):

Нет, нельзя считать отладку и тестирование считать синонимами - это два абсолютно разных процесса.

Для UI используют функциональное тестирование - при каждом прогоне автоматически запускается само приложение, и в тестах симулируется взаимодействие пользователя с интерфейсом(нажимаются кнопки мышки/клавитуры/другого устройства ввода, в поля вводится текст, переключатся значения в комбобоксах, и т.п.), с проверкой ожидаемого от интерфейса поведения(появление каких-то окон, надписей, изменение текста, рисунков, и т.д.).

Отладка же - это процесс, когда разработчик наблюдает за соcтоянием приложения в различные моменты выполнения кода - используя точки останова, перехват исключений, логирование, вызов внешних API, и т.д. Это вообще не тестирование - это ручной поиск причин некорректного поведения приложения.

Из инструментов для тестирования WinForms могу отметить систему UI-тестирования в Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise, а так-же такие инструменты, как [Quail](http://www.andreev.org/qa-testing-automation), [Ranorex](http://www.ranorex.com/),  и Microsoft UI Automation

Comment: Как я понимаю, описание тестирования я должен снабдить скриншотами, что выполняются ожидаемые мною действия? А в отледке, что описывается, обычно, методики, которые применялись?

Comment: В отладке, должно, наверное, описываться баги, которые были найдены при разработке и процессс их ловли и корректировки?

Comment: @iluxa1810, Да, в качестве вывода фунциональных тестов можно делать и скриншоты интерфейса, правда их проверку не автоматизировать, в отличии от логического "отклик корректен/некоректен" - поэтому обычно так не делают..

Comment: @iluxa1810, совсем не понял, что вы хотели сказать своими фразами про "отладку которая описывается". Точный синоним слова "отладка" - "наблюдение". Это не способ тестирования, а лишь экстренное средство для выяснения причин некорректной работы приложения в той или иной ситуации. Её применяют при исправлении ошибок в коде, который недостаточно покрыт тестами, или не покрыт тестами совсем. В отличии от тестов, она нудна, выматывает, и отнимает кучу времени разработчика, которое он мог бы посвятить написанию кода. Обычно применение тестирования исключает необходимость в отладке, и наоборот.